# Tabulator 4.5 "initial sort" by date and time not working

Tags: sorting, date, time, tabulator

I'm trying to sort my table by date and time (two separated columns).
I've tried to different ways, using:

```
initialSort:[ 
 {column:"date", dir:"asc"},//sort by this first
 {column:"time", dir:"asc"}//then sort by this second
],
```

or:

```
table.setSort([
  {column:"date", dir:"asc"}, //sort by this first
  {column:"time", dir:"asc"} //then sort by this second
]);
```

but none of them worked for me. it always sort by the last parameter (time).
If I use only "date" it works, or if I use only "time" also works. But when I add both, it sorts by the last one.

I'm using moment.js.

Columns format:

```
{title:"DATE", field:"date", sorter:"date", sorterParams:{format:"MM/DD/YYYY"}},
{title:"TIME", field:"time", sorter:"time", sorterParams:{format:"hh:mm A"}},
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a link to a working exampe in a JS Fiddle or Code Pen, it is hard to offer advice without seeing how your table is setup or how your data is structured

Answer (score 1):

Did you import [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in your code ?, date Sorting is dependent on moment.js